# error while using capybara to test a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

When I try to test a page using capybara, I get the following error
[Image for the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAlQr.png)

This is the code for my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.21'

gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'rspec-rails'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

And this is the code for `static_pages_spec.rb`:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do
  describe "Home page" do
    it "should have the content 'Sample App'" do
      visit '/static_pages/home'
      page.should have_content('Sample App')
    end
  end
end
```

When I replace the visit with get, the problem gets solved.

The same problem arises for the "page.should hava_content" part

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have the method provided by Capybara in your spec. Most likely you didn't mixed the Capybara DSL to rspec.

In your spec_helper.rb (top level in `spec` folder)

```
require 'capybara/rspec'

RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.include Capybara::DSL, type: :request
    ...
end
```

In your test file: `require 'spec_helper'`

Comment: thanx..it worked..but i had to replace spec_helper with rails_helper